# sequential execution inside a parallel for each loop

Tags: c#, .net, parallel-processing

My requirement is some thing like this. I have few independent jobs and few sequential jobs which abide to a contract. In my client app, inside Parallel For loop I need to make to sure the independent tasks get executed in any order but if they sequential they should be one after another. below is my code. Thanks,

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Reflection;
 using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Sample
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program p = new Program();
         List<IContract> list = p.Run();

        Parallel.ForEach(list, t=> t.Execute());
    }

    List<IContract> Run()
    { 
         List<IContract> list = new List<IContract>();
     Type[] typesInThisAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes();
      Array.ForEach(
        typesInThisAssembly,
        type =>
          {
            // If the type of this interface is not IChartView, continue the loop
            if (type.GetInterface(typeof(IContract).ToString()) != null)
            {
              var contractObj = Activator.CreateInstance(type, new object[] { }) as IContract;
               list.Add(contractObj); 
            }

          });

        return list;
     }
    }


public interface IContract
{
    void Execute();
}

public class XMLJob : IContract
{
    public void Execute()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Step1: Getting data from XML");

    }

}
public class DumpToDBJob : IContract
{
    public void Execute()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Step2: Dumping Data whihc came in XML");

    }

}
public class IndependentJob1 : IContract
{
    public void Execute()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("This is independent Job");

    }

}
public class IndependentJob2 : IContract
{
    public void Execute()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("This is independent Job ");

    }

}
}
```

**Desire Out Put**

This is independent Job
Step1: Getting data from XML
Step2: Dumping Data whihc came in XML
This is independent Job
Press any key to continue . . .

Can I do like this

```
      Program p = new Program();
         List<IContract> list = p.Run();

         IContract xj = list.Find(i => i.GetType().ToString() == typeof(XMLJob).ToString());
         IContract dj = list.Find(i => i.GetType().ToString() == typeof(DumpToDBJob).ToString());
         list.Remove(xj);
         list.Remove(dj);

         Parallel.ForEach(list, l => l.Execute());
        List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();

         Task t1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(xj.Execute);
         Task t2 = t1.ContinueWith((antecedent)=>dj.Execute());

        tasks.Add(t1);
        tasks.Add(t2);
        Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
```

Comment: My question is how  do I make sure if Step 2 comes only after Step1 not before that

Answer (score 3):

For all of the sequential tasks you should only have a single `IContract`.  The execute method of that contract should call the 2, 3, etc. methods that all need to be run sequentially.  If you have another group of 2 tasks to be run sequentially that would be another `IContract`.  You should not have more than one `IContract`s defined for a group of tasks that should be run in sequence.  If you don't want to do it that way you'll need to re-design your entire framework to introduce dependencies or something more involved.

Answer (score 0):

Your underlying problem is that you have no way to determine, using reflection, that `XMLJob` and `DumpToDBJob` should be part of a sequence.  You might set that up using custom attributes.

As Servy noted, for each set of sequential tasks, you could put only the first one in the parallel list, and have each task in the sequence start its successor.  When starting the lot using reflection, under this approach, you'd need to have some way to avoid starting `DumpToDBJob` (because it will be started as the last action of `XMLJob`).

Alternatively, you could make a wrapper task that executes a sequence of tasks in order, and put *that* in the list.

For example:

```
public class SequentialJob : IContract 
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<IContract> _children;

    public SequentialJob(params IContract[] children)
    {
        _children = children;
    }

    public void Execute() 
    { 
        foreach (var child in children)
            child.Execute();
    }
}
```

If you were creating an instance of this class manually, you could call `new SequentialJob(new XMLJob(), new DumpToDBJob())`.  But again, if you're using reflection, you'd need some way of identifying the correct objects to pass to this job's constructor, and in what order.

Comment: is it ok if I do like this. I know always that only those dlls should be sequqnetially executed. I have edited the question and added approach at the end

Comment: @PavanJosyula sure, if you know that those two jobs are the only special cases, then you can treat them specially.  Note that you can test types for equality; there's no need to call `ToString()`; you can just type `IContract xj = list.Find(i => i.GetType() == typeof(XMLJob));`